# variable in javascript statement

Tags: javascript, css

How does one add a variable string in this javascript statement?
where name may correspond to any valid string , say WebkitTransform or Moztransform,etc

```
document.getElementById('test').style.VARIABLE_NAME  =  'rotate(15deg)';
```

My code doesn't seem to work when i set the VARIABLE_NAME to WebkitTransform, but it works fine if I use WebkitTransform directly, as in without naming it via a variable.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to access members of a Javascript object.

[Dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation), which uses an identifier to access the member:

```
obj.member;
```

[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), which uses a string to access the member:

```
obj['member']
```

The latter uses a string to locate the member and you can just as easily use any expression. The value of the expression will be converted to a string so these are equivalent:

```
obj[{}]
obj['[object Object]']
```

If your expression is already a string it will be used as is, and in your case your variable holds a string so you can just do:

```
document.getElementById('test').style[VARIABLE_NAME]  =  'rotate(15deg)';
```

Comment: In general, foo.bar is syntactic sugar for foo['bar'].

Comment: But remember `obj['accept everything even spaces']`, while `obj.something with spaces` will probably not do what you want

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways of accessing values in javascript objects. The first one is by using the dot operator(e.g. object.memberName). The second one is by using the square bracket notation(e.g. object['memberName']).

Comment: memberName needs to go in quotes with the second example.